# How to define variable from function that I'm running loop over?

Tags: python, function, global-variables

This may be a super naive question, but I have a function that I'm trying to loop over with each item in a list being an input. The function is `get_t1_file()`

```
def get_bids_nifti(acq):
    bids_niftis = [f for f in acq.files if ('info' in f.keys() and 'BIDS' in f.info.keys() and "nii" in f.name)]
    if len(bids_niftis) > 0:
        return(bids_niftis.pop())
    else:
        return(None) 
    
def get_t1_file(sess):
    '''
        Function to pick the most desirable T1 file out of several in a session.
    '''
    #is_t1 = [any(['T1' in f.classification['Measurement'] for f in a.files \
    #    if 'Measurement' in f.classification.keys()]) for a in sess.acquisitions()]
    #t1_acq = [a for (a, v) in zip(sess.acquisitions(), is_t1) if v]
    
    t1_acq = []
    acqlist = sess.acquisitions()
    for acq in acqlist:
        if any(['T1' in f.classification['Measurement'] for f in acq.files \
            if 'Measurement' in f.classification.keys()]):
                t1_acq.append(acq)
    
    t1_file = None
    
    for acq in t1_acq:
        lab = acq.label.lower()
        if ("vnav" in lab) and ("moco" in lab) and ("rms" in lab) and not ("nd" in lab):
            t1_file = get_bids_nifti(acq)
            return(t1_file)
    
    for acq in t1_acq:
        lab = acq.label.lower()
        if ("vnav" in lab) and ("rms" in lab) and not ("nd" in lab):
            t1_file = get_bids_nifti(acq)
            return(t1_file)
    
    for acq in t1_acq:
        lab = acq.label.lower()
        if ("ax" in lab) and ("mprage" in lab):
            t1_file = get_bids_nifti(acq)
            return(t1_file)
    
    for acq in t1_acq:
        lab = acq.label.lower()
        if ("sag" in lab) and ("mprage" in lab):
            t1_file = get_bids_nifti(acq)
            return(t1_file)
    
    return(t1_file)
```

My loop to run the function over items in a list is:

```
t1_files = []
for s in session_ids:
    sess = fw.get(s)
    get_t1_file(sess)
    t1_files.append(t1_file)
```

But I have an error where the variable that is being returned is not defined. Is there something I'm missing from my loop or function to make sure `t1_file` is defined?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-16-b85e5ebfcdb1>", line 5, in <module>
    t1_files.append(t1_file)

NameError: name 't1_file' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the returned value of the function:

```
t1_files = []
for s in session_ids:
    sess = fw.get(s)
    t1_files.append(get_t1_file(sess))
```